# Is ReactDOMServer increasing bundle size?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` on the client side to turn some component into an HTML string (to use in a third party library) and I was wondering if adding the following will increase the bundle size or have any downsides on the performance or loading times:

```js
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
```

Comment: why don't you just check the bundle sizes with and without it?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that is at least until dynamic import is safe for library use is to move `getDataFromTree` and `renderToStringWithData` into a separate bundle `(react-apollo/server?)` similar to how `react-dom` bundles all its server rendering logic in `react-dom/server`. This would avoid bundling extra `react-dom` logic for the vast majority of users who never call `getDataFromTree` from the browser.